# ssis literal single string qoute around a date

Tags: ssis, powerbi, teradata-sql-assistant

I would like to know how to put a single quote around a ssis variable. This is my ssis expression

```
"INSERT INTO LOGS.LOG_FILES VALUES("+(DT_WSTR,29) @[User::Row_Count] +","+SUBSTRING((DT_STR,30, 1252) GETDATE(), 1, 19)+")"
```

This is my output or (Evolution value)

```
INSERT INTO LOGS.LOG_FILES VALUES(59,2020-05-28 13:59:42)
```

But I want the output to look like this

```
INSERT INTO LOGS.LOG_FILES VALUES(59,'2020-05-28 13:59:42')
```

or: How to include date value in single quotes  `'2020-05-28 13:59:42'`?

So how would the syntax look like on SSIS to accomplish this please?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to place the single quotes, first after the comma and the second before closing the bracket, like bellow:

```
"INSERT INTO LOGS.LOG_FILES VALUES("+(DT_WSTR,29) @[User::Row_Count] +",'"+SUBSTRING((DT_STR,30, 1252) GETDATE(), 1, 19)+"')"
```

Comment: @AmarCh, you can accept my answer if it helped you.